# Как запретить дублирующееся подключение css при вставке нескольких iframe

Tags: php, html, css, iframe, youtube

На сайте https://alisa-music.ru/#Clip вставлено несколько ютуб видео через iframe,первоначальную проблему со скоростью загрузки я победил отложенной через js вставкой.

Но заметил другую: каждый `iframe` загружает файл

> www-player-webp-vflovZ84d.css

В результате чего начинает ругаться Google PageSpeed на чрезмерную нагрузку

Могу ли я запретить дублирующую загрузку файла или полностью запретить загружать его в `iframe` и подключать самому?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет.

Но по идее браузер должен тянуть стиль из кеша - попробуйте загружать остальные ифреймы ПОСЛЕ подгрузки первого (тогда полностью загруженный css должен уже быть в кеше и доставаться оттуда).

Comment: Не сработало, но может подойдет другим